# HTTP header for sending PDF, problem in Firefox

Tags: php, http-headers

In windows when i save a pdf with firefox adobe reader plugin ocurs this problem. 
The file saved is: `http://www.example.com/opendocument.php_doc=._docs_doc01`

My headers are:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
//header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=doc01.pdf');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($pdf));
```

Original call is:

```
http://www.example.com/opendocument.php?doc=./docs/doc01.pdf
```

I'm not interest on attachment header. I must open into the website, not download o  external window.

Any idea?

Comment: After the file is downloaded, does it open correctly? (i.e. is it a valid PDF file, or is some other data also inserted before or after the file content?)

Comment: also when I download the file and try to open with firefox, this also works fine...

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try, note the quoting around the filename

```
Content-disposition: inline; filename="doc01.pdf"
```

Can't guarantee this, but it's taken from our PDF generation classes.

Comment: Using ' doesn't work for Firefox. I've used " which works great!

Answer (score 1):

Try un-commenting the `Content-Disposition: inline;` header, and use the correct capitalisation for `Content-Type` (that is, capital **T**)

Comment: HTTP header field names are case-insensitive.